# Angular 2+ Animation: Adding checkbox check effect to individual checkboxes that are generated by a loop

Tags: angular

I had a CSS animation for some checkbox "cards" (invisible checkboxes with labels that served as the interface for the checkboxes), but this CSS transition stopped working when I tried implementing it within an Angular project.

I'm very inexperienced with Angular and I'm working with some Angular code that's already written. I've figured out enough to get a simple animation working with these checkbox cards, the trouble I'm having is with the cards being generated with a loop. They each have the same (change) directive, and the labels have the same [@focusPanel], so any time I check one card it checks them all. I'd love to have these animated individually, but I have no idea how to do this with Angular.

The loop code:

```
<div class="checkbox-card"  *ngFor="let ancillary of ancillaryVm">
  <input type="checkbox" id="{{ancillary.id}}" value="{{ancillary.id}}" name="{{ancillary.id}}"  (change) ="updateSelectedIds($event)" />
  <label for="{{ancillary.id}}" [@focusPanel]='state'  [innerHTML]="getSafeHtml(ancillary)"></label>
</div>
```

part of my component.ts:

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'sp-ancillary-modal',
  templateUrl: './ancillary-modal.component.html',
  animations: [
    trigger('focusPanel', [
      state('unchecked', style({
          backgroundColor: 'green'
        })),
        state('checked', style({
          backgroundColor: 'yellow' 
        })),
        transition('checked => unchecked', animate('100ms ease-in')),
         ]),
    ]
})

      updateSelectedIds(event: any) {
        if (event.target.checked) {
          this.ancillaryIdListSelected.push(event.target.name);
          this.state = 'checked';

        } else {
          this.state = 'unchecked';
          const index: number = this.ancillaryIdListSelected.indexOf(event.target.name);
          if (index !== -1) {
            this.ancillaryIdListSelected.splice(index, 1);
          }
        }
      }
```

If it's more helpful, I've created a simpler version of this to test it out (although there isn't the loop in this example):
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h2fq6s

Any help would be much appreciated -- even just a high level outline of how I can go about doing this would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following would allow you to accomplish this.

Assign a TemplateRef `#checkBox` to the input, then use that in an expression to set the color `[style.background-color]="checkBox.checked ? 'red' : 'yellow'"`

```
<span *ngFor="let check of checkBoxes">
 <input #checkBox type="checkbox" id="check" (change)="toggleMove($event)" >
 <label for="1" [style.background-color]="checkBox.checked ? 'red' : 'yellow'"></label>
</span>
```

---

I revised Stackblitz to use your animations.

Assign TemplateRef `#checkBox` to the input, then use that to pass to your trigger `[@focusPanel]='checkBox.checked'`... your `(change)` just needs to call `checkBox.checked` and it will automagically toggle the boolean value.

```
<span *ngFor="let check of checkBoxes">
  <input #checkBox type="checkbox" id="check" (change)="checkBox.checked">{{checkBox.checked}}
  <label for="1" [@focusPanel]='checkBox.checked'></label>
</span>
```

Then change your animations to work on `true` and `false` rather than `checked` and `unchecked`... needs to match the value you are passing into the animation trigger `[@focusPanel]`

```
 trigger('focusPanel', [
    state('false', style({
        backgroundColor: 'green'
      })),
      state('true', style({
        backgroundColor: 'yellow' 
      })),
      transition('true <=> false', animate('200ms ease-in')),
       ]),
  ],
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bsygjv?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html